# Getting weird exception with Zend_Mail and Postfix

Tags: php, magento, email, zend-framework, postfix-mta

I run three Magento web stores. All the orders e-mails are working just fine, with the exception of 7 e-mails that didn't even got sent from the webserver. Upon investigating the issue I discovered the following logs:

Magento log:

```
2013-08-08T11:44:59+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /var/www/website.com/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
```

Postifx log:

```
Aug  8 12:44:59 bv-webserver postfix/sendmail[18647]: fatal: sales@website.com(33): No recipient addresses found in message header
Aug  8 12:44:59 bv-webserver postfix/postdrop[18648]: fatal: uid=33: malformed input
```

This is very strange, because hundreds of e-mails were sent just fine and only these 7 got this exception. In some cases the clients just purchased again from the store and then received the e-mail as expected.

I thought it could be a resource problem. But I run the newrelic agent and the server is at 20% load at most during peak hours (both memory and processors).

Edit: Forgot to mention, I run nginx with php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll always have an issue if you try to send emails without a recipient address. Postfix is telling you:

```
8 12:44:59 bv-webserver postfix/sendmail[18647]: fatal: sales@website.com(33): No recipient addresses found in message header
```

Fix that and you should be Ok.

You might need to look into why the application apparently lost the email addresses for the seven transactions in question.